# Can't create sequence in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, identity

I have tried to create a sequence in SQL Server 2008 using the following query,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE serial START 100
```

I got the following syntax error,

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SEQUENCE'.

How to create a sequence in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 11):

**You just cannot do this.**

SQL Server 2008 does not have the concept of a `SEQUENCE` - this is [a new feature in SQL Server 2012](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/11/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-sequence) [(MSDN documentation here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

Typically, you want to create an "auto-increasing" column for your table - in that case, use the `IDENTITY` column attribute instead:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
( TableID INT IDENTITY,
 .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `IDENTITY` column will do your task.

Get full details on msdn : [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How marc_s has wrote, SQL Server 2008 does not have sequences yet.
But we can use some trick to imitate sequences behaviour. Sometimes we need generate identifier for some table without inserting any data.
Or generate IDs for different tables.
In such situation I use this structure.

Create a table:

```
create table IdSequence (id int identity(1,1))
```

Then I use this script to generate Id:

```
begin tran 
 insert into IdSequence output inserted.id default values 
rollback tran
```

In my app it looks like:

```
    public Int32 GetNextId()
    {
        Int32 id = 0;
        using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            id = Session.CreateSQLQuery("insert IdSequence output inserted.id default values").UniqueResult<Int32>();
            transaction.Rollback();
        }

        return id;
    }
```