# Primary key violation error in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created two threads in C# and I am calling two separate functions in parallel. Both functions read the last ID from XYZ table and insert new record with value ID+1. Here ID column is the primary key. When I execute the both functions I am getting primary key violation error. Both function having the below query:

```
insert into XYZ values((SELECT max(ID)+1 from XYZ),'Name')
```

Seems like both functions are reading the value at a time and trying to insert with the same value.
How can I solve this problem.. ?

Comment: Well, Java has a synchronized keyword to prevent multiple threads from interfering with each other. I'd suggest you look up some multithreading links for the analogous construct in C#

Comment: @ChetterHummin No, his problem is that he is attempting to figure out the ID to insert at the application, when he should be letting the database handle it. Yes, he could also make a shared and synchronized ID variable but this would not prevent the issue of database synchronization. For example, consider the problem of a third party inserting into his table that doesn't use his shared variable. Then he still has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let the database handle selecting the ID for you. It's obvious from your code above that what you really want is an auto-incrementing integer ID column, which the database can definitely handle doing for you. So set up your table properly and instead of your current insert statement, do this:

```
insert into XYZ values('Name')
```

If your database table is already set up I believe you can issue a statement similar to:

```
alter table your_table modify column you_table_id int(size) auto_increment
```

Finally, if none of these solutions are adequate for whatever reason (including, as you indicated in the comments section, inability to edit the table schema) then you can do as one of the other users suggested in the comments and create a synchronized method to find the next ID. You would basically just create a static method that returns an int, issue your select id statement in that static method, and use the returned result to insert your next record into the table. Since this method would not guarantee a successful insert (due to external applications ability to also insert into the same table) you would also have to catch Exceptions and retry on failure).

Comment: above query is an example. Actually its table more than 50 fields and primary key filed is not auto increment. We have to insert the unique value explicitly.

Comment: @user1365604 Then maybe you should explain how your primary key is intended to work. From what you've explained so far it most certainly should be an increment column.

Comment: @user1365604 Why do you have to insert it explicitly? Why can't you correct your database table's design to auto increment for you? Do you know what an 'alter' statement is?

Comment: the above query(alter table XYZ modify column ID int auto_increment) gives an error(Incorrect syntax near 'modify'.)

Comment: I am thinking to lock the table while any thread read last value and insert the new record. Will it help me solve this problem. If yes, how can i do that.

Comment: For **SQL Server** it would be a column of type `INT IDENTITY` (SQL Server doesn't have a `auto_increment` keyword)

Comment: I don't think you can alter a column in a SQL Server table that has data in it to become an identity column. I could be wrong, but if I'm not then you'd have to create a new column, script the data in using IDENTITY_INSERT so you don't change the id then drop the original table and rename the new one

Comment: @user1365604 I think Greg may be correct, it doesn't work for SQL server. Instead migrate your data to the new table. Otherwise use a synchronized method like I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Set ID column to be "Identity" column. Then, you can execute your queries as:

```
insert into XYZ values('Name')
```

I think that you can't use ALTER TABLE to change column to be Identity after column is created. Use Managament Studio to set this column to be Identity. If your table has many rows, this can be a long running process, because it will actually copy your data to a new table (will perform table re-creation).

Most likely that option is disabled in your Managament Studio. In order to enable it open Tools->Options->Designers and uncheck option "Prevent saving changes  that require table re-creation"...depending on your table size, you will probably have to set timeout, too. Your table will be locked during that time.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for such problems is to have generate the ID using some kind of a sequence.

For example, in SQL Server you can create a sequence using the command below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.CountBy1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO
```

Then in C#, you can retrieve the next value out of Test and assign it to the ID before inserting it.

Comment: Sequences are only available in SQL Server 2012; OP is using 2008 which doesn't have that feature.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, Didn't know that. The post below suggest "IDENTITY" column. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238816/cant-create-sequence-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a higher [transaction isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) or more restrictive [locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx).

I don't use these features too often, so hopefully somebody will suggest an edit if I'm wrong, but you want one of these:

```
-- specify the strictest isolation level
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
insert into XYZ values((SELECT max(ID)+1 from XYZ),'Name')
```

or

```
-- make locks exclusive so other transactions cannot access the same rows
insert into XYZ values((SELECT max(ID)+1 from XYZ WITH (XLOCK)),'Name')
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, a higher transaction isolation level can help with this. Although it is *likely* that using `IDENTITY` is a better solution to the problem.

Comment: I think there is an isolation level called something like ReReadable. I'd have to check MSDN, but I think identity column would be better

Comment: @Greg: Just click the link to "transaction isolation level" in my answer to see what levels are available. You're right that an identity column would be better, but there are already 2 other answers suggeting that. Also, an identity column only works when your column is an integer *and* you can control the schema *and* you never have to set the column to a specific value.

Comment: sorry, completely missed the link. REPEATABLE READ is what I was thinking of.