# using MERGE for incremental insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where one column of the target table needs to be auto incremented . I do not have identity enabled on this column. So i need to pick the last number and add 1 to it , each time an insert is done.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61eb4/5

A similar scenario is given in the fiddle link. I do not want the productid of ProductChanges table to be inserted. Instead, i need the last id to be picked and i need it to be incremented and inserted for each new row

Comment: This is not merge specific. Also, this special identity scheme will limit concurrency to one insert transaction against this table at a time. No concurrency left at all.

Comment: Take some hints and implement a appropriate trigger on table, i have explained the simillar situation in my earlier stack answers.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891796/create-sequence-in-ms-sql-server-2008/18957485#18957485

Comment: yes.. looks like the instead of trigger should work fine. Will give it a try

Comment: it seems an instead of trigger needs to be enabled for all actions and not just insert , while using merge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code to get this working

```
DECLARE @intctr int
SELECT @intctr = MAX(productid)+1 from products
DECLARE @strQry varchar(200)
SET @strQry = 
'CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.seq_key_prd
    START WITH ' +convert( varchar(12),@intctr) +'  INCREMENT BY 1 ;'
    print @strQry
    exec( @strQry)


alter table Products
    add default next value for seq_key_prd
    for ProductId;
GO


--Merge statement for data sync
MERGE Products USING ProductChanges ON (Products.Productid = ProductChanges.Productid)
WHEN MATCHED AND Products.VendorlD =0 THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED by target then insert (productid,Productname,VendorlD)
values(default,productname,VendorlD)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
Products.ProductName = ProductChanges.ProductName ,
Products.VendorlD = ProductChanges.VendorlD;
```

Comment: So you aren't on 2008 then.

Comment: i am on sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

1)create sequence and set to target table.

example

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_seq
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;
```

2)create trigger for that sequence,to set the table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT 
ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.id is null)
DECLARE
v_id qname.qname_id%TYPE;
BEGIN 
SELECT table_seq.nextval INTO v_id FROM DUAL;
:new.qname_id := v_id;
END my_trigger;
```

Comment: The concept of sequence works in [tag:sqL-server-2012] not in [tag:sqL-server-2008] and it looks like you have `oracle` in mind while the database in MSsql

Comment: i tried using the Sql-server-2012 sequence statement. throws this error  NEXT VALUE FOR function can only be used with MERGE if it is defined within a default constraint on the target table for insert actions.

Comment: went ahead with the sequence function. added a default constraint as given in http://www.duncansutcliffe.com/?p=347 . and it worked!