# SEQUENCE in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to know if there is any way to have a `SEQUENCE` or something like that, as we have in Oracle. The idea is to get one number and then use it as a key to save some records in a table. Each time we need to save data in that table, first we get the next number from the sequence and then we use the same to save some records. Is not an `IDENTITY` column.

For example:

```
[ID] [SEQUENCE ID] [Code]  [Value]
1    1             A       232
2    1             B       454
3    1             C       565
```

Next time someone needs to add records, the next SEQUENCE ID should be 2, is there any way to do it? the sequence could be a guid for me as well.

Comment: `SEQUENCE` was introduced on SQL 2012.  It behaves similarly to Oracle SEQUENCE.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091%28v=sql.110%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Some trick to imitate a sequence [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238816/cant-create-sequence-in-sql-server-2008/33548758#33548758)

Answer (score 1):

As Guillelon points out, the best way to do this in SQL Server is with an identity column.

You can simply define a column as being `identity`.  When a new row is inserted, the identity is automatically incremented.

The difference is that the identity is updated on *every* row, not just some rows.  To be honest,  think this is a much better approach.  Your example suggests that you are storing both an entity and detail in the same table.

The `SequenceId` should be the primary identity key in another table.  This value can then be used for insertion into this table.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using multiple ways, Following is what I can think of

1. Creating a trigger and there by computing the possible value
2. Adding a computed column along with a function that retrieves the next value of the sequence

Here is an [article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server) that presents various solutions

Comment: Were you able to find the solution useful?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to do something like this:

```
-- Example 1

DECLARE @Var INT
SET @Var = Select Max(ID) + 1 From tbl;
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (@var,'Record 1')
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (@var,'Record 2')
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (@var,'Record 3')

-- Example 2

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1,2)

INSERT INTO ActualTable (col1, col2, sequence)
SELECT temp.*, (SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM ActualTable)
FROM #temp temp

-- Example 3

DECLARE @var int
INSERT INTO ActualTable (col1, col2, sequence) OUTPUT @var = inserted.sequence VALUES (1, 2, (SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM ActualTable))
```

The first two examples rely on batch updating. But based on your comment, I have added example 3 which is a single input initially. You can then use the sequence that was inserted to insert the rest of the records. If you have never used an output, please reply in comments and I will expand further.

I would isolate all of the above inside of a transactions.

If you were using SQL Server 2012, you could use the `SEQUENCE` operator as shown [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).

*Forgive me if syntax errors, don't have SSMS installed*

Comment: this will not work because if many people access at the same time, we can have the same id, unfortunately I'm not using 2012

Comment: @rgx71 how many users are accessing concurrently? I am just about to add alternative approaches. I personally would stay away from triggers.

Comment: If you can, try to get your hands on SQL 2012.  The Sequence command will prevent many of the headaches you describe above.

Comment: I can't move to 2012 for now. And about the question of Stuart, we can have many users trying to access at the same time.